# java.net.ConnectException MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, mysql, exception, driver

My code:

```
package staffrecords;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class StaffRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String databaseName = "SEGA";
        //String loginUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/" + databaseName;
        String loginUrl = "jdbc:mysql://dbprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk:3306/" + databaseName;
        String user = "SEGA";        
        String password = "*****";

        try 
        {                      
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(loginUrl, user, password);
            st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT StaffID FROM Staff";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next())
            {
                String staffID = rs.getString("StaffID");

                System.out.print("StaffID: " + staffID);
            }         
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }      
    }
}
```

And the error is:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

STACKTRACE:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at staffrecords.StaffRecords.main(StaffRecords.java:28)
```

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **

Last packet sent to the server was 2 ms ago.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)

Is there a simple solution to get the code to print out all the StaffID values in the table Staff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick online port scan for that address and it looks like the server side is not listening on port 3306. Maybe firewall configuration? Or just stopped server/wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

Looking like that Driver is throwing that

```
reason can be that

service not listening
Connections are not free
```